# selenium переключение вкладок

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Если в программе в одной вкладке открываются несколько сайтов поочередно, программа будет искать по последнему сайту?
Прим. такого кода:

```
    browser.get("google.com")
    browser.get("goodfruits.com")
    fruits = driver.find_element(By.ID, "fruits")
```

Найдет ли программа ID "fruits" на втором сайте, при учете того, что такой  ID существует?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Селениум, как и живой пользователь, работает с тем, что в данный момент открыто во вкладке. Нет никакой разницы.